# A problem about a continuous iterated function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb {R} \rightarrow \mathbb { R } $ be a continuous function such that  $f\circ f \circ f=\text{id}_\mathbb{R} $. Show that  $f=\text{id}_\mathbb{R}$.

Is there any hint to prove this? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: The composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777807/if-f-circ-f-circ-f-id-then-f-id